# Transfer learning in Keras with your own saved model

Tags: python, keras, lstm, sentiment-analysis, transfer-learning

I have seen some examples of transfer learning where one can use pre-trained models from **keras.application** (Xception, VGG16, VGG19, ResNet50 e.t.c) but what I want is to transfer the learning from the model I saved using **model.save('model.h5')**

This is my current model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(sequences, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
```

Now, Instead of saying

```
model_base = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

I want to load the saved model probably with **load_model('model.h5')** and add it as a layer to my current model.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.layers[0].set_weights([embedding_matrix])
model.layers[0].trainable = False

model.load_weights('model.h5')
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])

model_base = model
```

Dont forget to remove your classifier

Comment: I don't think this works. To load a model you should use Models.load_model but then if you do model = load_model('model.h5') you overwrite the model? I think you need to explain your answer

Comment: Yes, it is load_weights  not load